# Django error : communication failure with the server

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am beginner in django and i want to create a web page that enable the user to edit in the mysql database model and add to it and i have created it's views and models but when i submit the new data the browser gives me

**error : communication failure with the server.**

**view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import  render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from survey.models import *
from user_management.models import Candidate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django import forms
import settings
from emailtemplates import models
from email_sender.models import *
from report.pdf import DrawarmPDF,send_pdf_in_email
from decorators import superuser_required
from django.forms.models import ModelForm


class EmailTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmailTemplate
        exclude = ('body_text','subject','from_email','reply_to_email','body_text','body_html')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    


@login_required
@superuser_required()
def home(request):

    template_name='pdf'

    try:
        template = EmailTemplate.objects.get(template_name=template_name)
    except EmailTemplate.DoesNotExist:
        template=EmailTemplate(template_name=template_name)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailTemplateForm(request.POST, instance=template)
        if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                message = 'Your %s has been updated successfully.' % template_name        

    else:
        form = EmailTemplateForm(instance=template)

    query_results = EmailTemplate.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('emailtemplates/emailtemplates.html', 
                              {"query_results":query_results},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**html page**

```
{% for item in query_results %}
        <tr >
        <td><div class="usercheckbox"></div></td>
        <td class="firstname"><div class="editabletext">{{ item.template_name }}</div></td>
        <td>
            <a class="edit"></a>
            <a class="update" title="Update"></a>
            <a class="cancel" title="Cancel"></a>               
        </td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Email(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.TextField()
    from_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    to_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    reply_to_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    body_html = models.TextField()
    status= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,default='waiting')  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.to_email

class EmailTemplate(models.Model):
    template_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    from_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    reply_to_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    body_html = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.template_name
```

When i open the web page it gives me list with the table data correctly but the edit button gives me that error.

What am i missing ? can any one help me ? thanks.

Comment: i guess your mysql is not running, are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, because there is another web page that can access the database and edit it and it works fine. @Exprator